# Set a flag based on the value of another flag in the past hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following design:

```
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
| Shop | Date                    | SafetyEvent |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | 2018-06-25 10:00:00.000 |      0      |
| 1    | 2018-06-25 10:30:00.000 |      1      |
| 1    | 2018-06-25 10:45:00.000 |      0      |
| 2    | 2018-06-25 11:00:00.000 |      0      |
| 2    | 2018-06-25 11:30:00.000 |      0      |
| 2    | 2018-06-25 11:45:00.000 |      0      |
| 3    | 2018-06-25 12:00:00.000 |      1      |
| 3    | 2018-06-25 12:30:00.000 |      0      |
| 3    | 2018-06-25 12:45:00.000 |      0      |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Basically at each shop, we track the date/time of a repair and flag if a safety event occurred. I want to add an additional column that tracks if a safety event has occurred in the last 8 hours at each shop. The end result will be like this:

```
+------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| Shop | Date                    | SafetyEvent | SafetyEvent8Hours |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| 1    | 2018-06-25 10:00:00.000 |      0      |        0          |
| 1    | 2018-06-25 10:30:00.000 |      1      |        1          |
| 1    | 2018-06-25 10:45:00.000 |      0      |        1          |
| 2    | 2018-06-25 11:00:00.000 |      0      |        0          |
| 2    | 2018-06-25 11:30:00.000 |      0      |        0          |
| 2    | 2018-06-25 11:45:00.000 |      0      |        0          |
| 3    | 2018-06-25 12:00:00.000 |      1      |        1          |
| 3    | 2018-06-25 12:30:00.000 |      0      |        1          |
| 3    | 2018-06-25 12:45:00.000 |      0      |        1          |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

I was trying to use DATEDIFF but couldn't figure out how to have it occur for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't particularly efficient, but you can use `apply` or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, t8.SafetyEvent8Hours
from t apply
     (select max(SafetyEvent) as SafetyEvent8Hours
      from t t2
      where t2.shop = t.shop and
            t2.date <= t.date and
            t2.date > dateadd(hour, -8, t.date)
     ) t8;
```

If you can rely on events being logged every 15 minutes, then a more efficient method is to use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(SafetyEvent) over (partition by shop order by date rows between 31 preceding and current row) as SafetyEvent8Hours
from t
```

Comment: Will use correlated subquery, thanks. I thought it was this straightforward.